# The import javax.enterprise.context cannot be resolved in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

I've seen this problem before on Stack Overflow, but there was no solution, that did help. Here's what I get:

import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped; // The import javax.enterprise.context cannot be resolved

What I did:
 - added javaee.rar from GlassFish lib
 - imported: Web App Libraries, JSF 2.2, GlassFish System Libraries, J2EE 1.4 Libraries

None of this helped. I just can't find CDI library anywhere.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This sounds really weird and may be some caching problem. You should **Clean** your projects and restart Eclipse.

If this doesn't help you can try cleaning your workspace by adding `-clean` in your `eclipse.ini` as the first line. This will clean all the cached stuff when Eclipse starts.

The class you are trying to import is definitly included in the `javaee.jar` from Glassfish's lib folder.

Anyway you can also try to use the "Fix project setup" functionality of Eclipse by clicking the icon next to the import which is failing:

[image: fix project setup example]

This will try to find the class and propose a lib which contains it to add it to the classpath.

Comment: Thank you, nothing helped, still same. I've even created a new project. Added scrennshot on my question.

Answer (score 0):

`javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped` should be in GlassFish's libraries (weld-osgi-bundle.jar for me).

Maybe try to exclude J2EE 1.4 Libraries or set import order and see if this works.